# root path to home/index is not working with unicorn in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, path, root, unicorn

When I type into my  browser my web address www.moneytree.space, I get

[image]

How do I make /home/index to be displayed instead. I am using rails app and unicorn and nginx. In my config/routes.rb file the root is set to "/home/index". Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete index.html in the Rails app's public directory.

Comment: Thank you. It says in paragraph 2. Set up a default route and remove 'public/index.html'. Thank you for reminding me to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the root to "/home/index" in your routes.rb file, you're telling rails that /home/index should route to '/', not that '/' should route to /home/index

You can set '/' to a specific controller action like this:

```
get '/' => 'sessions#create
```

so all requests to your main webpage will go the create action of the sessions controller

Comment: "Welcome aboard" is the default public/index.html static page that prevent request to go to Rails app for '/' location

Comment: Thank you Stephani for you help :)